# Dynamic MySQL Procedure not working

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

```
Delimiter //
CREATE Procedure SearchTest(IN FieldName varchar(30),IN FieldValue varchar(30))
BEGIN
  SET @query = CONCAT('select count(*) from Some_table_name where ', FieldName,'=',FieldValue);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;

  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END //
Delimiter ;
```

---

```
mysql> call SearchTest('accession_no','L138362194');
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'L138362194' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: This is a case where using a parameterized stored procedure, doesn't prevent sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Your database table does not have a column `L138362194`.
You can fix that by adding such a column, or by choosing a column that exists.

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated because of missing quotes. Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/719ee4/4) that demonstrates the problem.

Modify the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE SearchTest(IN FieldName VARCHAR(30), IN FieldValue VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
  SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `some_table_name` WHERE ', FieldName, ' = \'', FieldValue, '\';');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: sql injection... sql injection everywhere